# Error with trailing slashes

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, slash, trailing

I have a Wordpress website and I want for example this URL:

http://mywebsite.com/tag/hola

to redirect automatically to

http://mywebsite.com/tag/hola**/**

The problem is that i couldn't put the trailing slash there. Could somebody help me? Is there something I could do with my htaccess to automatically redirect it? Thank you a lot!

Comment: post your permalink structure. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```